# Probability of being born on the same date

Tags: probability

There was a similar question on the one I am going to ask, but I felt that the answer to it was not very clear.  So please help me with this:

What is the probability of 3 people out of our extended family of 13, to share the same birth date (we have different birth months and years)?

Comment: What was the similar question?  What is the distribution of dates of the month (presumably 31 is less likely than 28)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: A simulation suggests about $5\%$ of cases of $13$ people have all different dates of the month, about $73\%$ have two sharing date(s) of the month but no more, about  $20\%$ have three sharing date(s) of the month but no more, and about $2\%$ have four or more sharing date(s) of the month.

Comment: If you assume 30 equally likely days per month, then the probability of _no matches at all_ among 13 people is about 0.047:  In R,  code `prod(30:18)/30^13` returns
$ 0.0468$ rounded to four places. That's according to computations in the famous "Birthday Problem." From there, it seems to me this scenario leads to somewhat messy combinatorics, so I followed @Henry;s lead and used simulation.

Comment: @Henry. Your code is elegant. Taking down my answer. Can't immediately find glitch in mine. Tracked about 100 samples and the two methods agree. May re-post mine depending on transparency. Your code is in Comment attached to my Answ, so quoting it here: "My simulation, reduced to one line to fit into a comment, is not producing the same answers as yours: `table(replicate(10^5,max(table(sample(1:31,13,replace=TRUE,prob=c(rep(48,28),45,44,28))))))`."

Comment: @BruceET For $30$ days in each month the probability of 3 or more sharing a number is $1-\dfrac{13!}{30^{13}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^6 \dfrac{{13-n \choose n}{30 \choose 13-n}}{2^{n}} \approx 0.2330466523$

Comment: @Henry. Thanks for combinatorial formula.